# Why does a Java thread have to reenter into lock if it is already taken by that thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, locks, reentrantlock

I was reading about Java threads and Reentrant Locks. ReentrantLock allow threads to enter into lock on a resource more than once. My question is why does the thread have to do so, if it already has a lock on the resource ? What is the purpose of this "Reentrance" ?

Comment: Thanks . But I was looking for the purpose of reentrancy rather than how it is implemented.

Comment: The purpose is to avoid deadlock in a situation when a Thread wants to access resource that is guarded by a lock that he is already holding - it was also explained in the duplicate question I linked...

Comment: If you read the accepted answer you'll find it covers that too.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there are two state variables in a class:

```
@GuardedBy("this")
List<String> countryList = new ArrayList<>();

@GuardedBy("this")
Map<String,String> countryCapitalMap  = new ArrayList<>();
```

Suppose some thread A is accessing `countryList`. This means that it has acquired the lock on "this". Now since locks are reentrant in Java, it means that the thread would also be able to acquire lock on `countryCapitalMap`. If acquiring the lock was per invocation (instead of per thread), then once thread A had acquired the lock on "this", I would have had to release it before it could acquire it again (to access `countryCapitalMap`).

Edit: Here's some code:

```
private synchronized insertCapital(String country, String city) {
    this.countryCapitalMap.put(country, city);
}

private synchronized getRandomCountry() {
   int randomInt = ...//randomly generated number
   return this.countryList.get(randomInt);
}
```

Reentrant locks would enable your thread to access both of these methods just by acquiring the lock once.

Comment: You'd be better off writing  actual code, rather than just annotating.

Comment: Added some code. Thanks.